# Adding multiple taxonomy filters to functions.php

Tags: functions, filters, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, multi-taxonomy-query

I need to add multiple taxonomy filters to the functions.php file to remove (3) irrelevant taxonomies from the Yoast SEO sitemap index. I have been able to successfully add one filter, but when I add the other two filters, I keep getting a 500 server error. I should note that I am a novice when it comes to PHP so I imagine there is something fairly simple that I am missing here.

The filter that works by itself:

```
function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
if ( 'scope' == $taxonomy ) return true;
 }
 add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
```

but the following code did not work for adding the two remaining filters:

```
function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
if ( 'scope' == $taxonomy ) return true;
 }
 add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );

function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
if ( 'layout_type' == $taxonomy ) return true;
 }
 add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );

function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
if ( 'module_width' == $taxonomy ) return true;
 }
 add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
```

Many thanks in advance for the help!

-Mark

Answer (score 2):

Try PHP's [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
    $excludes = ['scope', 'layout_type', 'foo', 'bar'];
    if ( in_array( $taxonomy, $excludes ) return true;
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the same function name more than once. Instead, rename them:

```
function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy_1( $value, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'scope' == $taxonomy ) return true;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy_1', 10, 2 );

function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy_2( $value, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'layout_type' == $taxonomy ) return true;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy_2', 10, 2 );

function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy_3( $value, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'module_width' == $taxonomy ) return true;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy_3', 10, 2 );
```

Or better yet, combine them in one tidy function:

```
function sitemap_exclude_taxonomy( $value, $taxonomy ) {
    if (   'scope' == $taxonomy
        || 'layout_type' == $taxonomy
        || 'module_width' == $taxonomy )
       return true;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 'sitemap_exclude_taxonomy', 10, 2 );
```